# Interchange of evaluation in double partial differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} ( [\frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x,y)]|_{x=0}) = [\frac{\partial}{\partial y} ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} F(x,y))]|_{x=0} $

?

Seems easy but I can't affirm whether it is true or not.

Comment: It is. When differentiating with respect to $y$, we hold $x$ constant anyway. So we could first set $x=\text{constant}$ and then set the constant to zero, or just set $x$ to zero at once.

Comment: @LVK: You could turn that comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is. When differentiating with respect to $y$, we hold $x$ constant anyway. So we could first set $x=\text{constant}$ and then set the constant to zero, or just set $x$ to zero at once.